# Extract the first line of text from cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have several cells each with multiple text lines. I want to extract just the first line of every cell:

Cell `A1`:

**AAAA BBBBBBBBB AA**

CCCCCCCCCCC DDD EEEEE

RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR

Cell `A2`:

**AAAA BBBB.**

CCCCCCCCCCC DDD EEEEE

RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the delimiter is a Line Feed, you can use the `CHAR` function

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH(CHAR(10), A1)-1)
```

Alternatively, try `CHAR(13)` which is Carriage Return

[Source](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2011/08/08/add-line-break-in-excel-formula/)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an add-on to [Shevek's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1334269/203559):

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH(CHAR(10),A1),IF(ISBLANK(B6), "", A1))
```

This will work with both single and multi line cells, as well as with blank cells.

Comment: Note to self: I'd bet there is a more concise way to achieve these additional checks...